# How to change external url of browsersync that is created using generator-gulp-angular

Tags: angularjs, gulp, generator-gulp-angular

Currently my external url look likes this

---

```
    Local: http://localhost:3000/
 External: http://192.168.0.4:3000/
```

---

But I want to change the External url from http://192.168.0.4:3000 to http://example.dev:3000

Answer (score 1):

That's not how external IP works, you can't point it to an arbitrary location.

When you run `ipconfig` or `ifconfig` in your command line (the command varies by OS) you get the external IP of your computer. Generally this is only accessible from the same network.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake. Previously I have mentioned as http://example.com:3000. I have edited my question now. Please refer it now. actually I want to change my external url from http://192.168.0.4:3000 to http://example.dev:3000.